# Remove excess information from string in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

Good morning. What I am trying to accomplish is easier said than done. With the code below, I return the following:

> Group is owned by: @{samaccountname=aduser1}
>
> Group is owned by: @{samaccountname=aduser2}

Here's the code:

```
$GroupList = get-content "Z:\text.txt"

ForEach($Entry in $GroupList){

$SubGroups = @()

$AllMembers = @()

$strGroupOwner = Get-ADGroup -identity $Entry -Properties ManagedBy | select managedby 

$strOwnerName = get-aduser -identity $strGroupOwner.managedby -properties samaccountname |select samaccountname

 "Group is owned by: " + $strOwnerName
```

I simply need to remove '@{samaccountname=' and the '}' at the end from my string $strOwnerName before passing it through to the next step to make my resume something closer to:

> Group is owned by: aduser1
>
> Group is owned by: aduser2

All I was able to find on Google was removing 'White Space'. Any help or reading material would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `$strOwnerName` is a `PSCustomObject`. To convert it to a string change

```
$strOwnerName = get-aduser -identity $strGroupOwner.managedby -properties samaccountname |select samaccountname
```

to

```
$strOwnerName = get-aduser -identity $strGroupOwner.managedby -properties samaccountname |select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
```

or

```
$strOwnerName = (get-aduser -identity $strGroupOwner.managedby).samaccountname
```

Comment: Works great! Although, I would still like to know how to rip apart strings and piece them back together again. Any takers?

Comment: a good place to start string manipulation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx
(i also amended the answer to include another solution)

Comment: Awesome. That link answered my questions. Marking as answer as soon as it will let me. Thank you Raf!

Comment: String manipulation is a completely different topic. And bear in mind that in your original version, you weren't actually getting a string - you were getting a string representation of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-expandproperty` parameter for [`select-object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx).

```
$strOwnerName = get-aduser -identity $strGroupOwner.managedby -properties samaccountname |select-object -expandproperty samaccountname
```

Also note that I've used `select-object` instead of the alias `select`; aliases should be avoided in scripts because they make an assumption about the execution environment which may not always be true.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I had to mark Raf as the answer as he did it first but you clarified so I gave you an upvote. Thanks!!

Comment: You can change who is marked as the answer. First is not always most right - it's not a race.